# Why do iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus screenshots send an incompatible alpha with RGB color space images?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios10

I'm trying to create a Bitmap Context in order to resize an image imported from the Camera Roll. Here's the code:

```
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                            newRect.size.width,
                                            newRect.size.height,
                                            CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                            0,
                                            CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                            CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));
```

I have two screenshots taken on an iPhone 7 and when I try to load them from the camera roll one fails and the other is successful.

**The first one is the one that fails:**

```
<CGImage 0x1701de3c0>
<<CGColorSpace 0x174a325c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Display P3)>
    width = 750, height = 1334, bpc = 16, bpp = 64, row bytes = 6000 
    kCGImageAlphaLast | kCGImageByteOrder16Little 
    is mask? No, has mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
```

Here is the error:

```
<Error>: CGBitmapContextCreate: unsupported parameter combination:
     16 integer bits/component;
     64 bits/pixel;
    RGB color space model; kCGImageAlphaLast;
    3840 bytes/row.
Valid parameters for RGB color space model are:
    16  bits per pixel,         5  bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,         8  bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst
    32  bits per pixel,         8  bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    32  bits per pixel,         8  bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst
    32  bits per pixel,         8  bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,         16 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast
    64  bits per pixel,         16 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast
    64  bits per pixel,         16 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    64  bits per pixel,         16 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,         32 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
    128 bits per pixel,         32 bits per component,         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast|kCGBitmapFloatComponents
See Quartz 2D Programming Guide (available online) for more information.
```

**The second one is the one that is successful:**

```
<CGImage 0x1705c0a50>
<<CGColorSpace 0x17402b7c0> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; sRGB IEC61966-2.1)>
    width = 750, height = 1334, bpc = 8, bpp = 32, row bytes = 3000 
    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast | 0 (default byte order) 
    is mask? No, has mask? No, has matte? No, should interpolate? Yes
```

**I couldn't find any clear information in regard to this particular situation. So, I'm wondering if anyone has any insight on this issue and a suggestion for a possible fix. I'm completely mind-boggled here.**

My crash logs indicate that this issue is only found on my iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you get for `CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef)` ?

Comment: @DonMag I updated the question to contain the CGImage info printed out at runtime.

Comment: Something was ringing a bell... but now I think it was unrelated. However, my guess is the `(kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Display P3)` -- the P3 part referring to Apple's "Wide Color" display, new to iPhone 7... not sure what you need to do to handle that, but might be a place to start looking.

Comment: Just an info. A developer on my company was taking screenshots manually from the device and tried to upload them to itunesconnect. It failed with this error. problem with RGB too :) looks like its not a problem in code!!

Comment: I'm really hoping it's just a bug on the iPhone 7 and not how I'm handling images in the app.

Any thoughts on explicitly specifying the alpha type? When I set the alpha type of the failing image to `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` it worked.

I'm not an expert with colors, and images, so I'm wondering if setting the alpha type will cause issues with the quality of the image received.

Comment: If it's really a screenshot there won't be any data in the alpha channel so it really doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ben in the context of screenshots only, I agree with you. However, the user has the ability to select any photo in their camera roll. So it might be a screenshot or it might not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I hope someone finds a better solution because this is a hack, but here's my workaround:

The `kCGImageAlphaLast` parameter is the unsupported piece of that bitmap info. For cases where the image is fully opaque you can use `kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast` and get the same result since the alpha pre-multiply, in the fully opaque case, is essentially a no-op (every pixel gets multipled by one).

But WARNING, if the image has any semi-transparent pixels their color will be wrong. In my case I expect fully opaque photos, otherwise the user is not using my app right, so I can live with this for now.

```
CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef);

// first try
CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                        newRect.size.width,
                                        newRect.size.height,
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                        0,
                                        CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                        bitmapInfo);

if (!bitmap && (bitmapInfo & kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask) == kCGImageAlphaLast) {

    // WARNING - only do this if you expect a fully opaque image

    // try again with pre-multiply alpha

    // clear alpha bits
    bitmapInfo &= ~kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask;
    // set pre-multiply last
    bitmapInfo |= kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast & kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask;

    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                        newRect.size.width,
                                        newRect.size.height,
                                        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                        0,
                                        CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                        bitmapInfo);

}

if (!bitmap) {
    // fail gracefully
}
```

Comment: This is the solution I will use for now. Like you, I hope someone can find a better solution soon. Thank you for your input.